# Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/.../maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

Tags: java, android, flutter, maven

when I try to build my flutter application I faced is problem:

> Could not determine the dependencies of task
> ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+.
> > Required by:
> > project :app > project :location
> > > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
> > > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

I have tried everything but nothing works:

1- I have a stable internet connection

2- I have tried updating or downgrading com.android.tools.build:gradle version

3- I have tried cleaning caches

4- I have tried removing all firebase libraries

5- I replaced JCentre() with mavenCentral()

There is my android -> build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and here is my android build.gradle file:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.bujupah.hestia"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    testImplementation'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.17.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

finally my flutter doctor result:

> [√] Flutter (Channel unknown, 2.0.0, on Microsoft Windows [version
> 10.0.19042.1052], locale fr-TN) [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1) [√] Chrome - develop for
> the web [√] Android Studio (version 4.0) [√] VS Code (version 1.57.1)
> [√] Connected device (3 available)
>
> • No issues found!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After trying everything that I found on Google. It took me almost 3 days. I finally found a workaround for me:

Upgrade your gradle to the latest version. In `android/build.gradle` file:

I edited `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'`

to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'`

---

And in `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file:

I edited `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip`

to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip`

My project is working again.

Comment: That's awesome that you got yours working! Mine already had those updated configuration lines, but it still won't build for the same reasons. **What led you to discover this solution?** I might be able to go down those steps and find out how to fix my build too

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons is that you entered the `Gradle Plugin Version` incorrectly or such `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1+'` (with + ), so the problem occurs.